# Spring MVC - redirect automatically append JsessionID

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

This is my handler method , if the user attribute in session is not null (He already logged in) forward him to success page , if not, redirect him to login page.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String showHome(HttpSession session) {
    User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
    if (user != null) {
        return "success";
    }
    return "redirect:/login";
}
```

The problem is , the first time I access my page, it redirect to login page but it automatically append jssessionId at the end of URL like this : "/login;jsessionid=FC75BC999410329E65785274BF0EB623". There is no problem when changing it to return "login".

Comment: are you using spring security?

Comment: No, i'm not , just simply pass session to handler method

Comment: are you using a tomcat container?

Comment: I am, tomcat 7 ,,.......

Answer (score 1):

In tomcat 7, make this change in your `tomcat_home/web.xml`

```
<session-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

Comment: What if i turn off cookie on my browser . Am I still being able to use session ?

Comment: You can use session, but if something else in your application requires cookies, it may cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by overriding the strictHttpFirewall, allowing semi-colons.

It's not an ideal solution, but I couldn't find a way to prevent Spring (or is it tomcat?) from appending the jsessionid to the redirect url

```
 @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

         .......

        @Bean
        public HttpFirewall allowSemicolonHttpFirewall() {
            StrictHttpFirewall firewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
            firewall.setAllowSemicolon(true);
            return firewall;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error in your spring-boot project then add the below property in your application.yml

```
server:
  servlet:
    session:
      tracking-modes: cookie
```

As spring eventually calls response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(url));

When it tries to redirect the request and http servlet response's method `sendRedirect` encodes the target URL and adds the JSESSIONID to it.

To avoid this we can configure tracking-mode and set it to cookie and this should solve the issue.